# Unable to Retrieve Default Windows Administrator Password in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation

I'm building an AWS CloudFormation automation document which creates a custom Windows 2016 AMI for me.

If I spin up an EC2 instance based on this AMI, I'm unable to retrieve the password.

[image: Get Windows Password]
[image: Password not available yet]

> Password not available yet. Please wait at least 4 minutes after
>   launching an instance before trying to retrieve the auto-generated
>   password.
>
> Note: Passwords are generated during the launch of Amazon Windows AMIs
>   or custom AMIs that have been configured to enable this feature.
>   Instances launched from a custom AMI without this feature enabled use
>   the username and password of the AMI’s parent instance.

There's also nothing shown in the AWS System Log:
[image: System Log]

The CloudFormation template looks like this:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "SSM Automation Document"
Parameters:
  SubnetId:
    Description: "ID of subnet to use for launching EC2 instance"
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id"
  KeyPairName:
    Description: "Name of EC2 key pair for logging in to the instance"
    Type: "String"
  SecurityGroupIds:
    Description: "The IDs of security groups that are permitted access to EC2 instance"
    Type: "List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>"
Outputs:
  AmiAutomationDocumentName:
    Value: !Ref "AmiAutomationDoc"
Resources:
  AutomationRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
            Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service:
                - "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                - "ssm.amazonaws.com"
        Version: "2012-10-17"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: "PassRole"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Action:
                  - "iam:PassRole"
                Effect: "Allow"
                Resource: "*"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonSSMAutomationRole"
  InstanceProfileRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
            Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service:
                - "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                - "ssm.amazonaws.com"
        Version: "2012-10-17"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: "PassRole"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Action:
                  - "iam:PassRole"
                Effect: "Allow"
                Resource: "*"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2RoleforSSM"
  InstanceProfile:
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
        - !Ref "InstanceProfileRole"
    Type: "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile"
  AmiAutomationDoc:
    Type: "AWS::SSM::Document"
    Properties:
      DocumentType: "Automation"
      Content: 
        schemaVersion: "0.3"
        description: "Create a new AMI"
        parameters:
          SourceAmiId:
            type: "String"
            description: "AMI to patch"
          TargetAmiName:
            type: "String"
            description: "Name of new AMI"
            default: "NewAMI_{{ global:DATE_TIME }}_{{ SourceAmiId }}"
        assumeRole: !GetAtt "AutomationRole.Arn"
        mainSteps:
          - name: "startInstance"
            action: "aws:runInstances"
            timeoutSeconds: 360
            maxAttempts: 1
            onFailure: "Abort"
            inputs:
              ImageId: "{{ SourceAmiId }}"
              InstanceType: "t2.micro"
              IamInstanceProfileArn: !GetAtt "InstanceProfile.Arn"
              KeyName: !Ref "KeyPairName"
              SecurityGroupIds: !Ref "SecurityGroupIds"
              SubnetId: !Ref "SubnetId"
              MinInstanceCount: 1
              MaxInstanceCount: 1
          - name: "stopInstance"
            action: "aws:changeInstanceState"
            maxAttempts: 1
            onFailure: "Continue"
            inputs:
              InstanceIds:
                - "{{ startInstance.InstanceIds }}"
              DesiredState: "stopped"
          - name: "createImage"
            action: "aws:createImage"
            maxAttempts: 1
            onFailure: "Continue"
            inputs:
              InstanceId: "{{ startInstance.InstanceIds }}"
              ImageName: "{{ TargetAmiName }}"
              ImageDescription: "AMI based on base image {{ SourceAmiId }}"
        outputs:
          - createImage.ImageId
          - startInstance.InstanceIds
```

Comment: It would be very useful if instead of telling the user to "wait *at least* 4 minutes", the UI gave a *maximum* wait period (i.e. the *longest* it will be before it can be used). That way the user wouldn't have to sit around periodically attempting to generate a key, but could instead set a reminder in the diary to come back at a specific time where it is 99.9% certain to be ready. IME these keys are often **not** ready after waiting 4 minutes. They should instead say "Come back in 20 minutes" or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Windows 2016 new Powershell scripts have been introduced. These need to be scheduled when building the AMI.

To accomplish this add:

```
- name: "installServices"
  action: "aws:runCommand"
  maxAttempts: 1
  onFailure: "Abort"
  inputs:
    DocumentName: !Ref "InstallServicesCommand"
    InstanceIds:
      - "{{ startInstance.InstanceIds }}"
```

and then:

```
InstallServicesCommand:
  Type: "AWS::SSM::Document"
  Properties:
    DocumentType: "Command"
    Content: 
      schemaVersion: "1.2"
      description: "Install base services"
      runtimeConfig:
        aws:runPowerShellScript:
          properties:
            - runCommand:
              - C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Scripts\InitializeInstance.ps1 -Schedule
              - C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Scripts\SendWindowsIsReady.ps1 -Schedule
```

Answer (score -4):

The below steps worked for me:

1. Connect to your Windows instance and customize it.
2. Search for and run the `EC2LaunchSettings` application if the Windows Server is 2016 or later, or `EC2Config` service application if Windows Server is 2012 R2 or earlier.
3. Enable Random (Retrieve from console)
4. Click Shutdown the system with Sysprep option.
5. Create AMI once instance got shutdown.
6. Then launch the system using new Keypair.